# Consumir arquivo .mdb e gravar no MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, servidor

Possuo um arquivo .mdb , e preciso injetar todos os dados dele no MySQL através de código PHP. O que eu faço é o seguinte:

```
// Executa comando via shell para upload do banco no mysql          
$scriptEsquema = shell_exec('mdb-schema uploads/arquivo.mdb mysql | grep -v ^DROP | mysql -u usuario meubancodedados');
$scriptInsert = shell_exec('mdb-export -D "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -H -I mysql uploads/arquivo.mdb MINHATABELA | mysql -u usuario meubancodedados');
```

- No meu computador funciona tranquilamente, mas ao passar para um servidor ele não funciona mais.

Existiria um outro jeito de fazer isso com PHP? Ou algo que devo fazer no servidor?

Comment: coloca o caminho inteiro na sua linha, se for linux `/var/www/html/teu-projeto/uploads/arquivo.mdb` e se for windows `c:\um\lugar\uploads\arquivo.mdb`, acredito que o bash execute sem identificar onde está seu diretório quando isso é feito da forma que especificou. ou simplesmente põe no código `cd/caminho/uploads/arquivo.mdb && mdb-schema ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é fazer uma conexão diretamente ao arquivo:

```
$db = 'uploads/arquivo.mdb';
$conn_mdb = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$conn_mdb->Open("DRIVER={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db");
if (!$conn_mdb) {
   echo "Xiii, faiô a conexão do MDB! ";
   die();
}
$sql = 'SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabela';
$res = $conn_mdb->Execute($sql);

$conn_mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Xiii, faiô a conexão do MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   die();
}

while (!$res->EOF) {
     mysqli_query($conn_mysqli,"INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2)
                                VALUES ('".$res->Fields['campo1']->Value."',
                                        '".$res->Fields['campo2']->Value."')");
    $res->MoveNext();
}
```

[**Aqui tem**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) mais sobre esse tipo de conexão.

Caso seu sistema seja Linux, é melhor utilizar uma ferramenta chamada [**MDBTOOLS**](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Utilizando-arquivos-Access-(.mdb)-no-seu-Linux).

A propósito, se a opção for só exportar os dados do seu mdb para o banco MySQL, o próprio programa [**Microsoft Access**](http://blog.systoolsgroup.com/export-data-from-ms-access-to-excel.html) tem uma opção para exportar os dados em formato de planilha Excel (CSV), cujo o formato é compatível com o MySQL.

Para Windows, também existem outras opções para exportar arquivos mdb diretamente para o MySQL. Como por exemplo o [**MySQL Front**](http://www.mysqlfront.de/).

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano, geralmente, este comando "shell_exec" é bloqueado por segurança no servidor de produção, sobretudo nas hospedagens compartilhadas.

Sugiro três coisas:

1/Verifique se sua hospedagem libera esse comando para rodar no servidor.

2/Exportar os dados desse BD para CSV, criar rotina em PHP para ler esse CSV e então dar carga no BD MySQL.

3/Se sua hospedagem for dedicada, então suba esses dados via SSH, se bem que a chance de liberar o comando "shell_exec" será maior pois o servidor será dedicado.

Então é isso. Espero que ajude de alguma forma as respostas.